ReactMapGl map gets stuck after clicking on "Center" button Body:
'm developing a React application using ReactMapGl to display an interactive map. I've implemented a feature that centers the map on the last known location of a vehicle when the user clicks a "Center" button.
The problem I'm facing is that the map gets stuck after clicking on the "Center" button. I'm unable to pinpoint the exact cause of the stuck behavior.
`
// Initializing viewport state
const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
  latitude: 45.4211,
  longitude: -75.6903,
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%",
  zoom: 0,
});

// Function to center the map on the last known location of a vehicle
const handleCenterOnVehicle = async (vehicleId) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/vehicle/${vehicleId}/localisations`);
    const lastLocation = response.data.data.points[response.data.data.points.length - 1];
    if (lastLocation) {
      setViewport({
        ...viewport,
        zoom: 2,
        transitionDuration: 1000,
      });

      setTimeout(() => {
        setViewport({
          ...viewport,
          latitude: lastLocation.latitude,
          longitude: lastLocation.longitude,
          zoom: 10,
        });
      }, 1000);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error while centering on the vehicle:", error);
  }
};

return (
  <ReactMapGl
    {...viewport}
    mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN}
    attributionControl={false}
    onViewportChange={(newViewport) => setViewport(newViewport)}
    mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11"
  >
    {/* Markers and other components */}
  </ReactMapGl>
);
`

